# Pancakeswap router v2 - getAmountsOut?

Tags: web3js, erc20, pancakeswap

What does getAmountsOut/getAmountOut and getAmountsIn/getAmountIn exactly do? There isn't an explanation in the [Pancakeswap docs](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/router-v2), so I'm not sure how could I use it. What's the difference between the two and with the 's' or none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the one with the "s" return the series of outputs resulting from a `path` of swaps. Whereas the ones without the "s" return the output for a single swap.

So if I swap along the path `["ETHUSDT", "USDTUSDC"]` then `getAmountsOut` will return the USDT output amount from the ETHUSDT swap and the USDC output amount from the "USDTUSDC" swap. The returned value will look like: `[usdtAmount, usdcAmount]`.

If I swap "ETHUSDT" then getAmountOut will return `usdtAmount`.

The inverse is true for getAmountsIn/getAmountIn.

It's defined here: https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/PancakeLibrary.sol#L63